# How to show a loading indicator during sending API request

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to show a loading indicator when request is awaiting for data

i'm using axios to send http request
and redux as state management

I've tried to define a loading object so that whenever i call a action ,set it to true 
but it won't turn to false when i get the data

here is what I've tried

```
    const INITIAL_STATE ={
    loading:false,
    success:null,
    msg:'',
    obj:[]
    }
    
    export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case SEND_PHONE:
          return {...state,
         success:action.payload.success, 
         msg:action.payload.msg, 
         obj:action.payload.obj
         ,loading:true};
         default:
          return state;
      }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it is to use asynchronus actions with redux-thunk (https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) which lets you dispatch mutliple times in an action

Your action might look something like this then:

```js
export function fetchSomething() {

    return dispatch => {
        dispatch({type:FETCH_PENDING})

        someApi.getSomeStuff()
            .then(response => {
                dispatch({type:FETCH_SUCCESSFULL, payload: response.data.results})
                return response.data.results
            })
            .catch(error => {
                dispatch({type:FETCH_ERROR, payload: error})
            })
    }
}
```

and your reducer looks something like this then

```
const initialState = {
    data: [],
    loading: false,
    error: null
}

function fetchSomethingReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case FETCH_PENDING:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true,
                error: null
            }
        case FETCH_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                data: action.payload
            }
        case FETCH_ERROR:
            return {
                ...state,
                data: [],
                loading: false,
                error: action.payload
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you will try to implement it using redux, it might not be straight forward and the optimal one.
I would suggest to have a look at this library which helps in putting the loading indicator for each request execution,

https://github.com/Lemoncode/react-promise-tracker#readme

Here you just need to wrap your axios calls with some callbacks that this library provides and put your loading component in place and everything will be handled by this library.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is that you can use `createAsyncThunk`, I find this is both easier to understand and work with.

With `createAsyncThunk` lifecycle actions (pending, fulfilled, rejected) will be generated for you, and all you need to do is to defined the reducers.

Below is taken and slightly modified from the official site from react-redux:

```js
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { userAPI } from './userAPI'

// First, create the thunk
const fetchUserById = createAsyncThunk(
  'users/fetchByIdStatus',
  async (userId, thunkAPI) => {
    const response = await userAPI.fetchById(userId)
    return response.data
  }
)

// Then, handle actions in your reducers:
const usersSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'users',
  initialState: { entities: [], loading: false },
  reducers: {
    // standard reducer logic, with auto-generated action types per reducer
  },
  extraReducers: {
    // Add reducers for additional action types here, and handle loading state as needed
    [fetchUserById.pending]: (state, action) => {
        state.loading = true;
    },
    [fetchUserById.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
        // once createAsyncthunk is 
        state.loading = false;
        state.entities = state.entities.concat(action.payload)
    }
  }
})

// define and export this so that you can access the state from your react component. 
export const getLoadingState = (state) => state.users.loading
```

With that you can use `useDispatch` in your react app as shown below:

```js
dispatch(fetchUserById(123))
```

In order to get the current redux state in `userSlice`, you can use `useSelector` like below:

```js
const loadingState = useSelector((state) => getLoadingState (state));
```

You may find more detailed information in the [link](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk)